# Designing a webservice

Tags: web-services, rest

I am trying to design a web-service which is used for vehicle parking ticket generation.

One of the APIs is
1. Input: Amount of money customer has deposited.
2. Output: Return the time till which his parking ticket is valid.

e.g. Consider the parking rate is £1 per hour and if the input is £3 and if the current time is 11.30am then the web-service should return 2.30pm. Hope that makes sense.

I was thinking about using RESTful service but I can not figure out what should be the resource. RESTful service does not sound like a good choice.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource could be just “parkingtickets”. The business action is to ‘create’ a parking ticket. It should be mapped to HTTP POST since the server is to create a resource (parking ticket).

```
POST /parkingtickets/
Body:   {amount: <amount>, starttime: <date-time>}
Return: OK, and {ticketid: <id>, endtime: <data-time>}
```

You can read more on the usage of HTTP verbs in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_APIs)

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking on the similar lines. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar before.

I built a php app/site where you call functions like this:
   `example.com/service/calculateparkingtime/?deposit=3.50`
and it would print out a json like this(with json headers):

`{state:true,parking_time:3.5}`

state is used for all responses and if there is an error there is also an 'error' key with an error message like:

`{state:false,
error:"Parking time exceeds the working hours of the car park.",
errorCode:"Park01",parking_time:2.5,exceeding_amount:1}`

If your API consists of such couple of small functions you can do the same.

service was used with either CURL or file_get_contents in php.

You can build the same app using other languages like ASP.NET and such.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you just want the answer to a question/calculation, i.e. you should use HTTP GET:

```
GET foobar.tld/ticketExpires/<amountInGBP> -> expiretime
```

I would probably return date+time, since £200 would return a time some days later....

your example would be:

```
GET foobar.tld/ticketExpires/3 -> "2:30pm" (or preferably "YYYY-MM-DD 14:30:00")
```

issues: different timezones between webservice and client? is amount of money always in GBP?

You also need to consider what the format for the response/answer should be: JSON, XML, plaintext, the client "should" to specify the desired format using headers. If you have a simple client just return smoe default format the client understands.